# What kind of relay is used for high-power RF front-end applications?

Tags: amplifier, rf, relay, ham-radio, low-noise-amplifier

My son and I are designing an RF frontend at 146MHz with a 300W amplifier on the TX side an an LNA on the RX side to be placed near an antenna feedpoint. The frontend will be inline to an existing feedline so we either need 2x SPDT's or 1x DPDT to bypass the LNA during transmit:

```
                 />>>TX AMP>>>\
-long feedline--<              >---short feedline---antenna
                 \<<<RX LNA<<</
```

A mechanical relay seems to make the most sense in terms of cost, but relays that can handle this much power do not have RF ratings ([not that I've found above 60W anyway](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/418/ENG_SS_108-98001_S%5B1%5D-1210543.pdf)).

How are high-power front-end switches typically implemented, specifically to minimize loss into the LNA but still transmit at 300W with a reasonable impedance match?

([Here is a video about the LNA design.](https://youtu.be/cMte9q1hoHM))

Comment: https://www.w6pql.com/using_inexpensive_relays.htm#HPWRrelays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coaxial relays are suited for this application,
eg Tohtsu CX800 series which can handle up to 1kW at 150Mhz.

price seems to be ballpark $200

That's a lot more than the price of the pcb-mount relay you've found.
your PCB relay is rated to break a 60W circuit, it can carry more more current than that if it's only switched while the circuit is inactive.

3A into 50 ohms is 450W and 150V  both are within the datasheet's parameters. (for the "D" variant)

It says it can withstand 1000V between open contacts but that may not be true at 150MHz, they probablty tested this at 400Hz or less.

So I guess the question is, do you feel comfortable testing this relay for yourself, and if it fails, what will the repair bill be?

Comment: Well, repair bill for a $5 part is $5, but not sure what secondary damage would take place if it shorted or opened, reflecting back into the amp. The MRF300AN can take 65:1 SWR so might be ok to test with.  We could ramp it out and see what melts ;)

Comment: Theres also a risk that you blow up the LNA but perhaps you can test with just wire there